# How to get information about remaining free space?

Tags: spacing, graphics

following scenario: I want to automatically generate a newsletter with some small articles, which is working fine. (I am generating LaTeX-code with data from a small database). But now I want to include some images to fill the space left (I want to have entirely filled pages), but I don't want to get more pages than needed for the articles.

So: is there a way to check with LaTeX, if there is space left on the last page and how much?

I hope you can understand what I mean.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you could use `\pagetotal` for this. Subtract it from `\textheight` to get the amount of space remaining.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\newdimen\spaceleft
\spaceleft=\textheight
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]

\advance\spaceleft by -\pagetotal
\typeout{Space on last page:}
\showthe\spaceleft
\end{document}
```

The result of this is:

> Space on last page:
>
> > 204.0pt.

Comment: Instead of multiplying something by -1 twice you can simply write `\advance\spaceleft by-\pagetotal`.

Comment: Any idea why  if I replace the last two lines with `\rule{1mm}{\spaceleft}`, the rule is pushed on the next page? There should be enough space for it right?

Comment: @tobiasBora --- One problem was a missing paragraph break before `\advance`. That meant the last paragraph wasn't included in page total. With that fixed, you still need to remove 3 or 4pt from the rule height to prevent a page break. I'm not sure why this happens exactly. I'll give it some thought, but you will probably get an answer much more quickly if you post a new question about it (because then someone like egreg or David Carlisle will see it).

Answer (score 8):

A nicer way to realise Ian Thompsons answer is to simply use `\dimexpr` rather than multiplying by -1 and adding the lengths:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]

\newdimen\spaceleft
\spaceleft=\dimexpr\textheight-\pagetotal\relax

Remaining space (above this line):
\the\spaceleft
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, this code snippet doesn't suffice (Ian Thompson's does). Please add the missing parts.

Comment: `\dimexpr` belongs to e-TeX extensions. That's why hoop jumping might be necessary for some plain TeX users.

Comment: @percusse But the question was about LaTeX not plainTeX.