# Nested inline math for new command with argument

Tags: math-mode, macros, delimiters, nesting, inline

There exists some consensus on the fact that one shouldn't use `$...$`, `\(...\)` or [`\ensuremath`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34830/120853) *inside* of `newcommand` (or `NewDocumentCommand`, ...) definitions to wrap passed macro arguments that are to typeset in math mode:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\newcommand*{\somecommand}[1]{
    \(#1\)
}
\somecommand{Hello!}
\end{document}
```

Here, `Hello!` will be typeset as math, but the user/author of that macro might have never known what hit them. This leaves something to be desired and [might be pretty surprising to the user](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment). It should work, for example, like `\somecommand{$Hello!$}`, where the `\newcommand` definition *omits* entering math mode. The author should be in command and be aware of math and text modes.

Now, I have a command that is supposed to *combine* the macro argument input with *more* math, in this case a single equal sign:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\newcommand*{\somecommand}[1]{
    #1\(=\)
}
\somecommand{\(A\)}
\end{document}
```

But this destroys math spacing:

[image: math spacing off]

We effectively have `\(A\)\(=\)`. That makes little sense. We can't define `\somecommad` to have `\(#1=\)`: this works when `#1` is just text, but not if it's math mode already (`LaTeX Error: Bad math environment delimiter`). That case would expand to `\(\(A\) = \)`.

The question is: why does that not work?

The advantage of `\(` over `$` is the clear possibility to match left and right delimiters. From the `\ensuremath` example linked above, it's obvious why the equivalent with `$` doesn't work: `$ $A$ = $` is legal syntax (`$$A$ = $` is not), but utterly useless (`A` is in text mode). Why does nesting the LaTeX inline math delimiters `\(` not work? It could just ignore any inner `\(...\)` pair. Technically, there's no reason it should/could get confused (as opposed to `$`) (?).

To solve the above problem (have a macro that appends an equal sign/some *more* math to its input), there seem to be only two solutions, both bad:

1. Have `#1\(=\)`, destroying spacing and requiring manual intervention like `\,`.
2. Have `\(#1=\)`. Spacing works, but the input argument *has* to be in text mode. This is terrible for IDEs, linters etc. (will mark math mode characters like underscores as wrong since they'll be used outside of math mode etc.).

---

EDIT: [Some more context to the question was requested](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/593218/nested-inline-math-for-new-command-with-argument/593242#comment1488350_593242). That context is pretty long; I tried to keep it to a usable minimum.

I am creating a template for an exam, based on the `exam` class. The formatting requirements are:

1. Top of the page has the question for that page.
2. Below is a box to pen in the answer (or part of it) to that question. The type of said answer can be flexible (usually a collection of required equations or a drawing).
3. Below that large box, there *might* be an *unknown* number (0, 1, ...) of further boxes to partition students' answers further.
4. All of this together should fill the current page vertically, automatically.
5. Eventually, after the exam concluded, a solution sheet will be made available for future reference. The answers should, thanks to `exam`'s facilities, be toggleable and filled in "automatically". **This is the core issue that lead to the original question above** (caller should enter arguments in math mode, but that "destroys" spacing aka we need manual intervention to get spacing right, but I wondered because nesting `\(...\)` should technically be possible arbitrarily)

Thanks to `tcolorbox`, the above can be achieved pretty nicely:

```latex
\documentclass[
    % answers,
]{exam}

\usepackage[
    raster,
    skins,
    % theorems,% `math` key
]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\NewDocumentCommand{\answerblock}{mmmm}{%
    \tcbitem[
        raster multicolumn=3,% Full width
        title={Rearranged equation (symbolic)},
        equal height group=A,% All boxes in this group are forced to the same height
        % No matter the boxes natural height, conditionally leave some space for manual
        % answer entries:
        minimum for current equal height group=2cm,
    ]
        % Problem: the caller will pass the argument already set in math mode (set
        % inside `\( ... \)` -> DO NOT USE `$...$`). See also
        % https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34830/120853 .
        % I asked about this here:
        % https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/593218/120853
        % We cannot put that argument *inside* another outer pair of `\(...\)`, it
        % will break.
        % This forces use to chain multiple math environments. This breaks the natural
        % spacing these have. Very sad and ugly, but we can hack a bit of space via
        % `\,`.
        % NOTE: DO NOT put text spaces here, they *will* show up in the result, since
        % we are in text mode in between the multiple math environments.
        #1\({}={}\)\ifprintanswers#2\fi%
    \tcbitem[
        raster multicolumn=2,
        title={Rearranged equation (numerical values)},
        equal height group=A,% All boxes in this group are forced to the same height
        % math,% from `theorems`; same issue with nested math ('Bad math environment delimiter')
    ]
        #1\({}={}\)\ifprintanswers#3\fi%
            \hfill{}\(=\)%
    \tcbitem[
        raster multicolumn=1,% 'Right' width
        title={Result},
        equal height group=A,% All boxes in this group are forced to the same height
        halign=center,
    ]
        \ifprintanswers#4\fi%
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{solutionoranswerarea}{%
    d()% Force top box to this height, as a *percentage* of the *remaining* space
    O{% Top box descriptive text
        Collection of required equations%
    }
    +b% Environment body itself
}{%
    \begin{tcbitemize}[
        raster equal height=rows,% Core functionality to automatic sizing, see below
        raster every box/.style={
            valign=center,% Alignment for *content* inside of boxes
        },
    ]
    % The following is just an adaption from '15.6.2 Placing Spaces', see `tcolorbox`
    % manual page 312, version 4.42 (2020-10-09).
    % The idea is that we have two (the default) columns in an outer raster, each with
    % only a *single* row: 2 columns, 1 row.
    % However, the rows consist of `tcbitemize` environments, hence we can 'cheat' by
    % having two such inner environments in which we can put however many columns and
    % rows as we please.
    % The `raster equal height=rows` makes it so both *outer* rows are forced to the
    % same height through a couple iterations (=compilations); *within* the inner
    % `tcbitemize`, we can use a dynamic space macro to adjust a height to match said
    % outer height automatically (`space to` and `add to natural height`).
        \tcbitem[% First column (of default 2)
            blankest,% blankest style sets everything to empty/0pt
            space to=\dynamicfillspace,% (Forced height - natural height) -> save to macro
        ]
            \begin{tcbitemize}[% Nested itemization
                raster width=2\linewidth,% 2 columns, so double back to original value
                raster columns=3,% Full width
            ]
                \tcbitem[
                    raster multicolumn=3,% Full width
                    add to natural height=\dynamicfillspace,
                    title={#2},
                ]
                        #3
            \end{tcbitemize}
        \tcbitem[blankest]% Second column
            \begin{tcbitemize}[% Second nested itemization
                raster width=0pt,% 'Hide' this entirely
            ]
                \tcbitem[% Fixed height to which the first column will adapt (in height)
                    blankest,% blankest style sets everything to empty/0pt
                    height=\textheight-\pagetotal,% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/207782/120853
                ]
            \end{tcbitemize}
}{
    \end{tcbitemize}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
    \question Please solve for \(d\). Write your answer below. Note the required fields.

        \begin{solutionoranswerarea}
            \begin{solution}
                \begin{align*}
                    a + b &= c \\
                    c &= 2d \\
                \end{align*}
            \end{solution}

            \answerblock{\(d\)}{\(\frac{a + b}{2}\)}{\(\frac{20 + 10}{2}\)}{15}
        \end{solutionoranswerarea}

    \clearpage
    \question Please solve for \(x\) \emph{and} \(y\).

        \begin{solutionoranswerarea}
            \begin{solution}
                \begin{align*}
                    z &= x \\
                    z &= y^{2} \\
                \end{align*}
            \end{solution}

            \answerblock{\(x\)}{z}{9}{9}
            \answerblock{\(y\)}{\(\sqrt{z}\)}{\(\sqrt{9}\)}{3}
        \end{solutionoranswerarea}

    \clearpage
    \question Please draw something.

        \begin{solutionoranswerarea}[Drawing]
            % Automatic solution requires extra work...
        \end{solutionoranswerarea}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Prints (`lualatex` on TeXLive 2020; requires a couple runs to get automatic spacing right):

[image]

[image]

[image]

With the `answers` class option *on*, it prints (last page is identical, solution to that is not part of this "M"WE):

[image]

[image]

Things that don't work to remedy this:

1. Using the `tcolorbox` theorems library with its `math` key. It leads to the same issue with `Bad math environment delimiter` when nesting
2. We cannot do `\(\answerblock{}{}{}{}\)` or even `\(\tcbitem ...\)`, aka wrapping the entire macro in math mode.

---

Question as above still stands:

the caller aka author should be in control of when to enter math mode for various reasons. Hence, we get `\(...\)` arguments to `answerblock`. Text input like `\answerblock{...}{...}{\sqrt{9}}{...}` is not acceptable (surprising, opaque behaviour and confuses syntax highlighting/linting). `\(\answerblock{}{}{}{}\)` would be okay but does not work, so we also [cannot use `\TextOrMath`, sadly](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/593242/120853).

So, manual intervention for spacing is required, since we apparently cannot nest `\(...\)`. Why is that so and is there a way around this? `\(...\)` should be nestable arbitrarily.

Comment: You could do `\newcommand*{\somecommand}[1]{#1\({}=\)}` but I'm not quite sure about the purpose... what about spacing after the equal sign?

Comment: Is LuaTeX possible? Then you could do `\toks0={\(A\)\(=\)}` and then postprocess the register with Lua to nuke the extra inline math tokens.

Comment: @campa Eventually, I also need a second argument `#2` that gets *appended* to the equal sign. Space on that side should also work. This is for an exam template with empty to-be-filled fields, hence it's not a usual typographic use-case. @Henri Menke, this is already using `lualatex` actually. I've done the Lua part of lualatex a couple times before, it works well. Thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: Well, you could add an empty group also after the equal sign, so you'll always have `\mathrel` spacing. Of course you must be careful about *other* spaces passed with the arguments.

Comment: Third option: don't put math mode at all and force the user to do `\(\somecommand{A}\)`. If the command is clearly intended for math only then that can be expected from the user, similar to other, predefined math commands.

Comment: Your question is very long but if this is for math why not the simple `#1=`  ? tex commands should almost always be math-only or text-only.  Note if your command is for use in text you need to remove all the white space in the defintion.

Comment: It is not clear what output you want as you say `#1\(=\)`  destroys spacing but `\(#1=\)` spacing works, but in both these cases you get a = with mathord class and no space, to get a relational = you would need `\(#1={}\)` or `#1\({}={}\)`  (I would use `$` not `\(` in a definition)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proposal:

- enclose the entire `\answerblock` call in `\(` and `\)`
- do not enclose the individual arguments in math delimiters
- close math mode at the start of the `\answerblock` command
- reopen math mode at the end of the `\answerblock` command
- use math delimiters around the full math expressions within the `\tcbitem`s

This way spacing is preserved without any extra syntax, and the editor/linter can also be tricked into thinking that the math is entered in math mode.

MWE (note the M):

```
\documentclass[answers]{exam}

\usepackage[raster]{tcolorbox}

% make syntax highlighters happy
\let\mathopen\(
\let\mathclose\)

\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\answerblock}{mmmm}{%
    \mathclose%
    \tcbitem[
        title={Rearranged equation (symbolic)},
    ]
        \(#1=\ifprintanswers#2\fi\)%
    \tcbitem[
        title={Rearranged equation (numerical values)},
    ]
        \(#1=\ifprintanswers#3\fi\)%
            \(\hfill{}=\)%
    \tcbitem[
        title={Result},
    ]
        \ifprintanswers#4\fi%
    \mathopen%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcbitemize}
% linter also happy
\(\answerblock{d}{\frac{a + b}{2}}{\frac{20 + 10}{2}}{15}\)
\end{tcbitemize}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Tex commands should almost aways be math or text, not both, note latex has `\^` and `\hat` for text and math accents even though technically they could have been combined.

However if you really want to combine in to one, LaTeX provides `\TextOrMath` for that purpose.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\newcommand*{\somecommand}[1]{\TextOrMath{#1 = \ignorespaces}{#1={}}}

an = in text with word spacing \somecommand{ABC} foo

an = in math with \verb|\mathrel| spacing  $\somecommand{ABC}x$

\end{document}
```

Comment: The OP seems to want `\somecommand{$ABC$}` though. From the question: "It should work, for example, like `\somecommand{$Hello!$}`, where the `\newcommand` definition _omits_ entering math mode". So if the argument is already math, stay in math, if the argument is text, do something else.

Comment: @Marijn hard to tell exactly what OP wants (I may edit this if the question is clarified) but if the current contest is text `\somecommand{text}` and `\somecommand{$math$}` both do something reasonable (= with text spacing)

Comment: I provided more context to the original question. It mainly boils down to nesting `\(...\)` and my lack of understanding why that is not possible.

Comment: @AlexPovel of course it would be _possible_ to define `\(` to do nothing in math mode rather than give an error but it generates an error by design. Your main concern seems to be `caller should enter arguments in math mode, but that "destroys" spacing`  but that is a misunderstanding on your part there is no reason to lose correct spacing here.

Comment: @AlexPovel specifically it is your use of `\(=\)` (I would always use `$` rather than `\(` in macros, but that is not the issue here) `\(=\)` is equivalent to = and will make an = without math releation spacing. It is simply that coding error that is giving you spacing issues, not the definition of `\(`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Okay, I don't understand. In the definition body of `\answerblock`, for testing purposes I now changed all `\(...\)` to `$...$`. `chktex` now yells at me to reverse this. (Why would you prefer `$` there even if this is LaTeX code?) Of course this didn't solve the issue; how can I actually solve the question of the OP? Leaving *out* all math mode (`\(` or `$` both) is also not an option, see the revised question (`$\answerblock{}{}{}{}$` is not an option). I originally used `\(` because that is at least *theoretically* nestable -- `$` is *by definition* not nestable.

Comment: `\(` is essentially a user-level error catcher. It is the same as `$` but it checks that you are starting and ending math correctly. That is something useful in hand written document code, but if you are writing a tested macro that may be called millions of times over its lifetime checking every time that the `\(` and `\)` match is rather pointless.  It is same as I would usually use `\def` (or a non-checking expl3 version) rather than `\newcommand` in internal definitions as the checks that `\newcommand` does are useful at the top level but less so in internal code.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you very much, that was a helpful explanation.